# Assert that map contains not null vales by given keys

Tags: java, spring

I have a code that consumes map of properties with string keys which represents some kind of context. And I want this code to fail if the map does not contain some of the required properties.

The corresponding code might look like this:

```
SomeResultType businessMethod(Map<String, String> context) {
    Assert.isTrue(context.containsKey("A"), "A property must not be empty");
    Assert.isTrue(context.containsKey("B"), "B property must not be empty");
    Assert.isTrue(context.containsKey("C"), "C property must not be empty");
    // ...
}
```

I wrote a simple replacement by myself with signature like this

```
public static <K, V> void mapContainsKeys(Map<K, V> map, K... keys)
```

But I think that something like this must be already implemented somewhere. So **I'm searching for library replacement of this code**.

It would be great if Spring guys implemented something like this in `org.springframework.util.Assert`.

Comment: Use the great [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) library for assertions. Which lets you write better assertions and contains a whole lot of nice things for Maps, Collections etc. etc.

Comment: I don't know of a library for this specific thing, but note that Map has a containsKey() method that would be more appropriate than null checking.

Comment: @M.Deinum it is not about unit testing, it is about input validation.

Comment: @ohlec Yes, you're right. I updated the question.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota you were testing for null values, now after your last edit you are checking for the map to contain certain keys... very confusing

Comment: I see why this was confusing. map.get(key) == null doesn't mean the map doesn't contain the key. HashMap allows null values for instance

Comment: @rptmat57 yes you're right. May be the question is unclear. I want to validate input parameter to a method. The validation means checking if map contains all required keys. The result of validation should be exception with clear description on what was wrong.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138552/discussion-between-oleksandr-shpota-and-rptmat57).

Answer (score 2):

if you want to just check that a map contains a list of keys, use this:

```
map.keySet().containsAll(keys)
```

if you want more details, to know which ones were missing:

```
Set<String> missingKeys = new HashSet<>(keys);
missingKeys.removeAll(map.keySet());
```

and then:

```
if (!missingKeys.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(missingKeys + " keys missing");
}
```

Comment: No, it is not a solution. The idea is to validate input Map and throw `IllegalArgumentException` with good description.

Comment: define "validate". in your code you are just checking for null

Comment: @rptmat57 - He already defined "validation" as "not having null as an entry for certain keys".

Comment: Thanks, but as I already mentioned, I implemented validation by myself and the aim of this question is only to find library replacement of my code.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota ...and that is something Stack Overflow does **not** permit. People flag/vote to close those posts that want others to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource*. Such post is considered off topic and should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you had to write a helper method means that you are probably manipulating maps all over your code.
Looks like a code smell to me, you should probably map your properties to an object that you can validate once and pass everywhere.

Since you are using Spring, and if you are using Spring Boot (most people do nowadays), you can use [`@ConfigurationProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) to map your configuration properties to an object.
This way you can also add [validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation) like `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` and make sure your properties are valid.

Comment: I already have abstraction on top this map and it has ability to validate itself. For purpose of this question I simplified my code as much as possible. It is not about `@ConfigurationProperties`. The idea is to pass a context to a business operation, and different business operations might require different execution context

Comment: ok, I don't know your domain, but can't your "business operation" be materialized by some generic interface ? like `interface BusinessOperation<T> { SomeResultType businessMethod(T argument); }` with `<T>` being your typed "execution context" ? If the number of properties is infinite/out of your control, then I don't know anything better than [@rptmat57](http://stackoverflow.com/users/597548/rptmat57) 's solution : `map.keySet().containsAll(keys)` or your helper method.